# Refreshing data and calling backing bean method after set time

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf, rerender

In my page i have a rich:datatable which obtains the data from a backing bean. I would like to call a method in the bean to refresh the data and after refresh the table.

I currently have the following situation, but the the method is being called but the table remains un refreshed

```
<f:view>
    <h:form>
        <a4j:region>
            <a4j:poll id="poll" interval="5000" action="#{attendance.updateData()}" enabled="true" reRender="poll,attendanceList"/>
        </a4j:region>
        <rich:dataTable width="500" id="attendanceList" reRender="scroller"
            rows="#{attendance.getRows()}" columnClasses="attendance"
            rowClasses="even-row, odd-row"
            value="#{attendance.getData()}" var="a"
            style="width:100%" rendered="#{attendance.renderAttendanceList}"
            onbegin="waitCursor(true)" oncomplete="waitCursor(false)">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, I define the action to be called in the `a4j:poll` itself:

```
<a4j:poll id="poll" interval="1800000" action="#{viewManagedBean.actionToBeCalled}" enabled="true" reRender="poll,attendanceList"/>
```

Also please notice that you are defining `a4j:poll` and `rich:dataTable` in two separate forms and that you are not specifying `prependId="false"` in your forms. However you are referencing to the dataTable (in `reRender`) without the form ID.
EDIT based on OP comments. Here is how you deal with the prepend id, you have two possible ways:

1. Just add `prependId="false"` to your forms
2. Don't add a `prependId="false"` but define your forms IDs, and use these ids in the `reRender` part, something like this: `reRender="theIDYouGaveToYourForm:theIdOfYourDataTable"`

Comment: I switched to javascript since some kind of refreshing was actually occurring. now however the whole page is being refreshed...

Comment: of course it will, since you are using a `h:commandLink` with an `action`. I think using `actionListener` would fix it (I'm not sure). However, I would advice using `a4j:poll` since it has so many good features

Comment: i tried using the a4j:poll you gave me. I can tell that the backing bean method is being called every 5 seconds, just like i set it. However the table isn't updating.

Comment: please see second part of my asnwer. I will give more details, see updated answer

Comment: i take it however that if they are in the same h:form i would no need to use the formId to reference them?

Comment: the backing bean method is being called but the table isn't being refreshed

Comment: i changed hform to <h:form id="attendanceTableForm"> and the a4j:poll reRender to reRender="poll,attendanceTableForm:attendanceList". Still no change

Comment: please try to put datatable inside `a4j:outputPanel` and try to update it instead (its id in the reRender attribute)

Comment: <a4j:outputPanel id="attendanceTableContent"> <rich:dataTable ..  and reRender="poll,attendanceTableForm:attendanceTableContent" />   still nothing

Comment: last thing I can advice here: add `ajaxRendered="true"` to the outputPanel and `limitToList="true"` to the poll.